# Genie Effect in Android Fragment

Tags: java, android

I have spent a lot of time looking for a reference for how to apply a genie animation effect like iOS in iOS to an android fragment. But no ideas, where getting I haven't found anything helpful so far. Can anyone tell, me how do I can achieve a genie motion in android. I am welcoming your best Your ideas and suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: Check out Canvas and drawBitmapMesh.